# Limitting to one decimal point

Tags: javascript, html, decimal

I need to stop users from entering multiple decimal points, I already have code that wont allow symbols and letters and I came up with this to stop it from allowing more than one decimal point but this wont allow any decimal points.

```
function ValidateDecimal(o) {
    if (o.value.length > 0) {

        var objReg = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
        if (objReg.test(o.value)) {
            o.style.backgroundColor = '';
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
        } else
            o.style.borderColor = 'red';
        o.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
        return false;

    }
}
```

Is there something wrong inside the code that anyone can spot?

I've looked allover stack overflow and didn't find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: This piece of code doesn't work it wont allow any decimal points, but I want it to allow 1 and 1 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine thanks for everyones help, it was a problem with the objReg variable, although it doesn't work in compatibility mode in ie10

```
   function ValidateDecimal(o) 
   {
        if (o.value.length > 0) 
        {

            var objReg = /^\d{0,20}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/;
            if (objReg.test(o.value))
            {
                o.style.borderColor='';
                o.style.fontWeight='';
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
            }
            else
            {    
                o.style.borderColor='red';
                o.style.fontWeight='bold';
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;
            }    
            return false;
        }
   }
```

(EDIT)

This Javascript is fine in IE compatibility mode now it was a problem in the html, it didnt like oninput and it needed to be on onkeyup. I had to use onkeyup because I've already got another function being called with on keypress to not allow letters and other symbols.

Comment: It was *also* a problem in the `if` structure and in the border color setting. And the code now allows `42.` too, which might be OK, but obviously wasn’t the intent in the original code. Moreover, you have redefined the goal to that at most 20 digits are allowed in the integral part (probably harmless, but also pointless).

Comment: The If and else structure made no difference I tested it thoroughly, was a bad practice obviously, not one I normal work by. I don't think 42. causes errors but I will test how it works in my database later. Yeah I've changed the the maximum allowance of digits to.

I noticed the borderColor myself after I posted it as originally it was used for backgroundColor to red but that looked rubbish

Answer (score 2):

You need curly braces in your `else` clause. Regexp itself is fine.

```
if (objReg.test(o.value)) {
    o.style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
} else {
    o.style.borderColor = 'red';
    o.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
}
```

Without the braces your codes was equivalent to this one (basically always disabling your submit button):

```
if (objReg.test(o.value)) {
    o.style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
} else {
    o.style.borderColor = 'red';
}
o.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, it always puts the red border round and bold text when a decimal point is entered

Comment: So possibly the problem is somewhere else. Could you provide working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I tried making it in js fiddle there but it wouldn't do anything, I've not really had much use of that before that's all

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id='myField' />

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
var myField = document.getElementById('myField');
myField.addEventListener('input', function (prev) {
    return function (evt) {
        if (!/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value)) {
          this.value = prev;
          this.style.borderColor = 'red';
          this.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
          document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
        }
        else {
          prev = this.value;
          this.style.borderColor = '';
          this.style.fontWeight = '';
          document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
        }
    };
}(myField.value), false);
</script>
```

**(EDIT)**

Based on your comment I have edited answer which will work for multiple fields.
Just add a class name to the input fields to handle in javascript

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class='decimalField'  />
    <input type="text" class='decimalField' />
    <input type="text" class='decimalField' />

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
var decimalField = document.getElementsByClassName('decimalField');

for(var i = 0; i<decimalField.length; i++){
    decimalField[i].addEventListener('input', function (prev) {
        return function (evt) {
            if (!/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value)) {
              this.value = prev;
              this.style.borderColor = 'red';
              this.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
              document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
            }
            else {
              prev = this.value;
              this.style.borderColor = '';
              this.style.fontWeight = '';
              document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
            }
        };
    }(decimalField[i].value), false);
}
</script>
```

Comment: That works @Salim but I have hundreds of text boxes for what I really want to use this for, I'm just making a dummy application at the moment, would this allow me to get element by class?